# update Angular-UI bootstrap datepicker options after date change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the angular-UI Bootstrap datepicker. I have two dependent datepickers, which represent start & end date. So that means, the start date is not allowed to be bigger then the end date and vice versa.

As the user can choose a date in a period of time, the min and max range for the start and end date changes. However right now, I did not really find a way to update the min and max date, as it is not done automatically. Anyone knows how to do that?

I tried calling an update function which updates the `shipSearchStartDateOptions.maxValue` or the `shipSearchEndDateOptions.minValue` which would be called in the ng-change part, however that did not work at all. The options did not change the min or max date.

Right now, even the initial settings of the options are not working. Even though I have nearly the same code as stated in the examples.

This is the console log of the options at the initial call:

> Object {maxDate: Mon Apr 04 2016 13:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), minDate:
>   Sun Mar 13 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)}
>
> Object {maxDate: Mon Apr 04
>   2016 13:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), minDate: Sun Mar 13 2016 00:00:00
>   GMT+0100 (CET)}

JS code:

```
$scope.firstAvailableDate = DataProvider.getFirstTimestamp();
$scope.lastAvailableDate = DataProvider.getLastTimestamp();
$scope.searchStartDate = $scope.firstAvailableDate;
$scope.searchEndDate = $scope.lastAvailableDate;

$scope.shipSearchStartDate = {
  opened: false
};

$scope.shipSearchEndDate = {
  opened: false
};

$scope.shipSearchStartDateOptions = {
  formatYear: 'yy',
  maxDate: $scope.searchEndDate,
  minDate: $scope.firstAvailableDate
};

$scope.shipSearchEndDateOptions = {
  formatYear: 'yy',
  maxDate: $scope.lastAvailableDate,
  minDate: $scope.searchStartDate
};

$scope.shipSearchStartOpen = function() {
  $scope.shipSearchStartDate.opened = true;
};

$scope.shipSearchEndOpen = function() {
  $scope.shipSearchEndDate.opened = true;
};

$scope.updateOptions = function () {
  $scope.shipSearchStartDateOptions.maxValue = $scope.searchEndDate;
  $scope.shipSearchEndDateOptions.minValue = $scope.searchStartDate;
};
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <p class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchStartDate"
           ng-change="clearShipSearch(); shipSearch(); updateOptions();" uib-datepicker-popup
           is-open="shipSearchStartDate.opened" datepicker-options="shipSearchStartOptions"
           show-button-bar="false" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="shipSearchStartOpen()">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
           </button>
        </span>
     </p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
     <p class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchEndDate"
          ng-change="clearShipSearch(); shipSearch(); updateOptions();" uib-datepicker-popup
          is-open="shipSearchEndDate.opened" datepicker-options="shipSearchEndOptions"
          show-button-bar="false" />
       <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="shipSearchEndOpen()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
          </button>
       </span>
     </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob already pointed out, your datePicker options objects in controller and HTML don't match.

Also, you shouldn't need to call the update method(s) on ng-change. Datepicker would update the options automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Your binding the datepicker options in the markup to:

```
shipSearchStartOptions
shipSearchEndOptions
```

but your controller objects are:

```
shipSearchStartDateOptions
shipSearchEndDateOptions
```

They need to match.